# How to prevent a TabItem from being selected & keep focus back on last edited control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to achieve the functionality to stop the user from selecting the new tab when current tab has pending changes. From below reference, I am able to show the message & stop the user from selecting the new tab but facing problem to set the focus back on last focused control in the tab item. Please help.

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an `Async` `Await` command method in your ViewModel which has an IsTabEnabled boolean property bound to the TabItem that is set to true once your work is completed?

```
private async void ProcessDataCommandAction()
{
   //Business logic
   await task;
   isTabEnabled = true;
}
```

Xaml:

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsTabEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged"}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but due to business need, I can't disable other tabs.